# apt-get failed in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, apt-get

My Bitbucket Pipelines has been configured for some time but today my builds started to fail on apt-get command. While apt-get update I am getting error "command not found". It's running in bitbucket pipeline.
Pipeline

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:   default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y zip
          - pip3 --version
          - pip3 install -U awscli
          - npm install
```

Underlie error i am getting in bitbucket pipeline.
Error:

```
    + apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y zip
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.38.132 80]
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Err:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.38.132 80]
Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.38.132 80]
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.38.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.38.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.38.132 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: By changing the node image to 14, able to fix this issue.

Comment: Can't find the relevant duplicate question for this, but the issue was the security packages being moved.